# What is the maximum number of methods a Dart project can have?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

According to the [Java class file specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jvms/second_edition/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659) the method limit count for a project is **65535**. Does Dart for Flutter have a similar limit of some sort?

Comment: Never heard of such a limit. I guess the limit is the amount or RAM.

Comment: @dev.bmax Android allows multiple dex files though, so yeah

Comment: This limitation is not a problem for regular Java projects, since you can have multiple class files. It is mostly relevant to Android projects, because the build toolchain combines all of the bytecode into a single classes.dex file. So the question is does Flutter running on Android have a similar issue?

Comment: @MacaronLover It sure does, but you need to use the MultiDex support library.

Answer (score 2):

Dart VM has no limitations on the number of methods in the program.

There is however a limitation on the number of classes in the program, namely Dart VM would not be able to run an application with more than 65536 classes, because of how it lays out objects in the heap - each object in the heap has a 16-bit field called "class id" which contains the index of a class of this object.

Comment: The question was about methods, not classes.

Comment: @VyacheslavEgorov Can you think of a way to get the number of classes on the heap by getting the max class ID? I thought observatory, but I can't remember if it's possible to connect to Dartium or if that only works for cmd line.

Comment: Oop, nevermind. Was able to use content shell and connect observatory to it.